# Mounting cifs/samba volume as a directory in android

Tags: root-access, mount, cifs

I'm using a custom rom based on cyanogenmod 13, my device is rooted and I have Xposed installed.
I'm looking for a simple app to mount samba or cifs volume in a directory on my android devices, years ago I used Cifs Manager and Mount Manager but it seems they have been discontinue and now I can't find valid alternatives.
I tried the latest versions of Cifs Manager and Mount Manager I could find but they didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your sure kernel supports SELinux and cifs module

You additionally need [SELinuxModeChanger](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=selinuxmodechanger&fdid=com.mrbimc.selinux) Alternatively type: `setenforce Permissive` as su in terminal.

A patched version of CIFS manager which uses (mount command) and needs SuperSU from chainfire. You can get this from XDA developers; Patched [CIFS manager](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?s=1dfdbb52aa2d05d8bcafcddde2ed17e8&p=53760495&postcount=537)

Alternatively you can create a cifs mount point from terminal and give IP address and username of your NAS:

```
su --mount-master -c busybox mount -o username=guest,rw,noperm,iocharset=utf8 -t cifs //192.168.xxx.xxx/cifsshare /path-to-mount-in
```

change back SElinux mode to enforcing:

```
setenforce Enforcing
```

And you're done

Credits

[Mounting a network share into the filesystem [ROOT]](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/856208/-guide-how-to-mount-a-network-share-into-the-filesystem-root-/)